# ¿Se pueden pasar como parametros una funcion en otra funcion en c++?

Tags: c++

intento crear como funcion este pedazo de codigo, pero la funcion que tengo dentro de este codigo, no se como pasarlo como parametro, como hacer para que lo reciba.

```
 if ((matriz_juego[i][j] == *casilla2 && matriz_juego[i][j-1] == 
  *casilla2
    &&  matriz_juego[i][j+1] == *casilla2)) {

      cumplir_primera_condicion(matriz_juego,caracteres,puntaje,
        aleatorio.numero,aleatorio.numero2,aleatorio.numero3,i,j);
      int d = cumplir_primera_condicion(matriz_juego,caracteres,puntaje,
        aleatorio.numero,aleatorio.numero2,aleatorio.numero3,i,j);
        if(j == 0){
          puntaje = d - 1;
        }
        if(j!= 0){
          puntaje = d;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No me queda claro. No veo ninguna función en ese *pedazo de código*. Podrías, por favor, editar y aclararlo un poco ? ¿ Tal vez un ejemplo de lo que esperas conseguir ?

Comment: cumplir_primera_condicion(parametros) , esta otra funcion que cree aparte.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Se pueden pasar como parametros una funcion en otra funcion en c++?

Se puede.

#### Propuesta.

Al parecer la función que quieres ejecutar se debería llamar `cumplir_primera_condicion` y recibe una `matriz_juego` (que parece un arreglo bidimensional de algo) y 7 parámetros adicionales que parecen ser números y devuelve un entero.

C++ es un [lenguaje de tipado fuerte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_fuerte) y [estático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_tipos#Tipado_est.C3.A1tico), esto implica (entre otras cosas) que todo (incluido las funciones) tiene un tipo subyacente, los tipos de las funciones de C++ siguen el siguiente formato: `retorno([parámetros...])`, así que el tipo de tu función podría ser parecido a esto:

```
int(char **, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)
```

Para hacer que sea un puntero a función hay que añadir el nombre tras el tipo de retorno:

```
int(*puntero_a_funcion)(char **, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)
```

Y así puede ser usado:

```
int cumplir_primera_condicion(char **, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)
{
    // Hacer cosas
    return 0;
}

void funcion(bool(*puntero_a_funcion)(char **, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)) {
    if ((matriz_juego[i][j] == *casilla2 && matriz_juego[i][j-1] == *casilla2 &&  matriz_juego[i][j+1] == *casilla2)) {

        int d = puntero_a_funcion(matriz_juego,caracteres,puntaje, aleatorio.numero,aleatorio.numero2,aleatorio.numero3,i,j);
        if(j == 0){
            puntaje = d - 1;
        }
        if(j!= 0){
            puntaje = d;
        }
    }
}

// Llamar
funcion(cumplir_primera_condicion);
```

Puedes ver que escribir esto es muy engorroso, así que normalmente se aconseja usar alias de tipos:

```
int cumplir_primera_condicion(char **, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)
{
    // Hacer cosas
    return 0;
}

// Alias del tipo
using condicion_t = bool(char **, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)

// Llamada mas clara
void funcion(condicion_t *puntero_a_funcion) {
    ...
    ...
}

// Llamar
funcion(cumplir_primera_condicion);
```

Comment: en este caso matriz_juego[][] es una matriz de tipo char, no int, entonces como lo coloco ahi? char normal?

Comment: y tambien tengo una duda, la variable puntaje, la coloco en los parametros de funcion() ?

Comment: @antoniovm99 no tengo ni idea. Has añadido un fragmento de código tan carente de contexto que sólo he podido hacer conjeturas, y no creo que pueda conjeturar qué hacer con tu variable `puntaje` que ni se para qué se usa, ni dónde se declara, ni cuál es su tipo.

Comment: Dices que `matriz_juego` es una matriz de `char` ¿es de tamaño estático o dinámico?, no se ve en tu código ni su declaración ni su definición.